# Why isn't my c++ comment closing in VS code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, flex-lexer

I'm not understanding why my block comment won't close using /* */

```
/* 
Name:                                Net ID: 
Course:                                    Assignment: Part 1
Programming Environment: WSl VS Code
                         C++ compiler- g++
                         C++ debugger- gdb
Purpose of File: Generate lexical analyzer using flex

 */
```

[image: Snapshot]

It's recognizing /* */ if used in the same line, but nothing more. I just downloaded VS code, though I am  somewhat familiar with c++ and this has me stumped..I apologize for the noobie question. Thank you in advance for any guidance on this issue I'm having.

Comment: Did you try to compile this? I cannot see anything wrong in this comment. What error do you get? Please, note that the compiler is the only reliable authority. Whether or not syntax highlighting is working correctly is a secondary issue. It may be subject of a missing extension or plug-in of your IDE.

Comment: Btw. If this is `rules.l` (a lex or flex file), it's not really C++ code. lex/flex have their own source code (where C/C++ code can be mixed in). However, the code has to be compiled to yield the actual C (or C++) code which in turn can be compiled with a C or C++ compiler. Maybe, your IDE is confused by the suffix `.l`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put comments into a (f)lex scanner definition, but they must not touch the left margin. Every line of the comment must be indented by at least one space or tab.

I don't know if VS code really understands (f)lex syntax, but you'll have to indent your comments in order to process the file with flex.